# PHP Arrays - Disable Option when it is Unsupported in Different Option Array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to disable an option when it is disabled in a different option array. I have made some sample code;

```
$options = array(
    // slug, conflicting/unsupported options
    array('mainoption', array('option1', 'option2')),
    array('option1', null),
    array('option2', null),
    array('option3', array('mainoption')),
);

foreach ($options as $option) {
    if(this option == 'option1' and is disabled in a different option array) { // how?
        echo 'disabled';
    } else {
        echo '<input type="text" name="' . $option[0] . '">';
    }
}
```

How can I disable the input in the foreach when the option is marked unsupported in a different array? (in this case, is it defined unsupported in 'mainoptions')

But for me this seems impossible. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Make it a regular for loop (with counter), then check the value at `$mainoptions[$i]`. That said, why are the other options not their own array, but instead a sub-array of `$options`? That seems to overcomplicate your code. I'd put them in their own array, `$mainoptions`, so you can check as described.

Comment: `if(in_array($option, $mainoptions)) {//code here}`. Also, you can use `[]` to define arrays. I, personally, find that using square brackets allows the code to be more legible

Comment: And now I see that `'mainoptions'` have only a key (`'option1', 'option2'`), where `$options` have key-value pairs (`'option1' => null`). That also seems odd? What does *"defined unsupported"* mean?

Comment: @domdom "defined unsupported", the arrays where the unsupported options are stored, e.g. the array in `mainoptions`

Comment: @domdom I'm trying to understand your first comment but can't really figure out how you meant it. Can you please explain it using a code sample?

Comment: Ah, now I understand (I think). In that case, @ctwheels already gave you a suitable solution. I still find your code/explanation confusing though. Why not rename `mainoptions` to `unsupported_options`, for example? Why have it be a sub-array of `$options`? Why not make a class, `Option` and give them a `$supported` field?

Comment: I, personally, would take @domdom 's approach by creating a class. Classes are beautiful things and save your time in the long run. You don't always have to use them but I would suggest that 99% of the time, you make things class-based